# При перезагрузке Unity перестают работать кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Непонятная ситуация. У меня есть `Canvas` куда добавлены несколько кнопок, также туда добавлен `EventSystem`. В иерархии обьектов также есть свой `EventSystem`. Запускаю сцену: не работают кнопки, не жмутся. Я беру делаю дубликат (Ctrl + D) `EventSystem`, переношу его из `Canvas` в главную иерархию, запускаю сцену - работает, кнопки жмутся. Сохраняю, закрываю Unity, захожу снова в юнити? запускаю сцену - не работает, пока не сделаю указанные выше действия, с тем что прошлый `EventSystem` в иерархии висит. Почему? Что это может быть?

Comment: Возможно вы случайно отключили какой-либо компонент у этого EventSystem?

Comment: Да нет ничего не отключено